# Pre-set position of spawned node

Tags: java, javafx, position, nodes

I'm trying to make app that spawns new draggable nodes on pretty big pane(which is child of scrollpane), but this node should be spawned in the center of the screen.

Q is: Are there any methods to pre-set X,Y coordinates of these new imageviews?

For example:

```
 button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    Bounds bounds = scrollPane.getBoundsInLocal();
    Bounds screenBounds = scrollPane.localToScreen(bounds);

    int mX = (int) screenBounds.getMinX();
    int mY = (int) screenBounds.getMinY();

    Rectangle2D primScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    int x = (int) ((primScreenBounds.getWidth() - mX) /4);
    int y = (int) ((primScreenBounds.getHeight() - mY) /4);   

    /*
    System.out.println("X coords:" +x);
    System.out.println("Y coords:" +y);
    */

    pane.getChildren().addAll(new ImageView(imgvw.getImage()));
    //somehow set coordinates of new ImageView

    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you'd set the position de´pends on the layout you use. However assuming you use `Pane`, you could use

- `layoutX` and `layoutY` *or*
- `translateX` and `translateY`

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(imgvw.getImage());
iv.setLayoutX(x);
iv.setLayoutY(y);
pane.getChildren().add(iv);
```

Other layouts, e.g. `StackPane` automatically set `layoutX` and `layoutY`. In this case you could set `managed` to `false`

```
iv.setManaged(false);
```

or use the appropriate parameters for the layout type.

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on the parent the `ImageView`s are placed in, though in general you should be able to position `Node`s with `Region#positionInArea()` (`Region` is superclass of `Parent`). Note that this is a protected method, meaning you might want to create your own parent (e.g. by extending `StackPane` for example).

That being said, there are plenty of `Parent` `Node`s, each providing their own unique behavior. Try to make sure that the desired behavior cannot be achieved using any of those before creating your own implementation. (And since you dont specify any positioning behavior, its hard to make recommendations)

Comment: Well, all I would like to do is to use`int x` and `int y` coords as spawning coords for `new ImageView`, but Im not able to figure it out. :/